# How to identify which type of files from blob data?

Tags: angular, image, pdf, blob

Just want to check if anyone worked on getting the types of files from blob data. As I always receive file type of blob is always as text/xml.

Here i need to identify the file type from blob data and show as following

- If it is image, then it will be src for  tag
- If it is PDF, then it will render in PDF viewer

etc..

If you have any solutions, Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to work on BE and add a Content-type header with the format.

A solution I would prefer would be to insert more informations into the response (such as the name of the incoming file and its format) wrapping your blob file in something else.

For example, the BE could send you a response like this:

```
{
   "name": "sampleImage",
   "type": "image/jpeg",
   "extension": "jpeg",
   "content": "{base64 of your file}"
}
```

Inside you enter all the necessary information and the basic 64 format of the file you need, to be translated into blob and downloaded.

If you want a more precise answer try to insert more informations.

For me this is more a job for the BE and after a job for the FE.